# Modem Routers + L2 Managed Switch. VLANs and balancing

Tags: networking, modem, switch, vlan, load-balancer

I just got a TP Link TL-SG3210 and I wanted to test some things and I wondered if I was correct (or not) on some ideas I have and tests I want to do.
This is mostly hipotetical cases, but I want to know if it would work (or not) and If would make any improvement on the network.

**Case 1:**
If I have 1 internet connection (modem router with 4 ports) + 8 port switch.

- Does the modem care about the connections / ports to handle the request? Meaning, if I have only 1 port connected to handle 6 pcs simultanously or it would be better to have 2 ports with 3 pcs on each? Would this have any impact on performance, latency or bandwith?
- Can I connect 2 o more ports of the modem to the switch and assign each to a different vlan? So it would balance the traffic from the different computers to the modem?.

**Case 2:**
Taking a similar example as before but with a bigger switch (24 ports) and 2 internet connections:
Creating 2 Vlans with a group of ports and internet connections: lets say 10 ports for each vlan + internet connection.

- Can a single gigalan connection from the switch to the modem router would be able to handle all the requests of the 10 users at the same time? (of each vlan)
  Let's say each user is watching a youtube video at the same time.
- The modem routers have 4 gigalan ports. What if I connect 2 or more to the switch and add'em to each Vlan? So each vlan would be 10 pcs + 2 internet (same internet connection). Would it be possible to balance the requests and lower the latency time and response? Would it mean any improvement?

**Case 3:**
Based on case 2.
Create VLan1 with the 2 different internet connections
Create Vlan2 with the PC's
Create VLan3 with Vlan1 and Vlan2.

I wanted to balance the load of the internet connections. Yes, I know I should use a Load Balancer for this, but I wonder if it could work by just ussing the switch and if it would be "smart" enough to balance the traffic of the internet connections.

- Could the switch balance the traffic of the 2 internet conections? Would it be able to handle them?
- Or it would be better o assign each internet connection to a different vlan?

I know it's kindda of a mess, but just curious about how to get more performance on the network for each sittuation.

Thank you in advance for the advices.

Ofesad

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Case 1: If I have 1 internet connection (modem router with 4 ports) + 8 port switch.
>
> Does the modem care about the connections / ports to handle the request? Meaning, if I have only 1 port connected to handle 6 pcs simultanously or it would be better to have 2 ports with 3 pcs on each? Would this have any impact on performance, latency or bandwith?

It doesn't matter because in nearly all such modem-routers, the four external ports are a separate component – literally a switch – which is *usually* connected to to CPU through only a single internal port. So when you're going through the router proper (to/from Internet), the throughput available will be limited to that single "CPU port" at most. (And by the CPU itself.)

> Can I connect 2 o more ports of the modem to the switch and assign each to a different vlan? So it would balance the traffic from the different computers to the modem?.

Kind of, although if the router itself doesn't have VLAN support, it means all of your such "VLANs" would still be in the same subnet (they wouldn't be L2 isolated as the modem's internal switch would bridge between them).

So I think it would *work,* but would be completely pointless. The external LAN ports aren't the bottleneck, the internal CPU-switch link is.

(Normally this wouldn't be done using VLANs – it would be done with *link aggregation,* generally using 802.3ad/LACP between two switches.)

> Can a single gigalan connection from the switch to the modem router would be able to handle all the requests of the 10 users at the same time? (of each vlan) Let's say each user is watching a youtube video at the same time.

10 YouTube streams even at 4k resolution would [only barely reach](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/78358?hl=en) ~200 Mbps. That's nowhere close to your 1 Gbps port.

In most cases a single gigabit port can handle quite a few users. TCP's built-in flow control will make sure they all cooperate (e.g. two simultaneous downloads would automatically reduce to ~500 Mbps each, without overwhelming the network).

> The modem routers have 4 gigalan ports. What if I connect 2 or more to the switch and add'em to each Vlan? So each vlan would be 10 pcs + 2 internet (same internet connection). Would it be possible to balance the requests and lower the latency time and response? Would it mean any improvement?

No, that's not where the latency comes from.

> Case 3: Based on case 2. Create VLan1 with the 2 different internet connections Create Vlan2 with the PC's Create VLan3 with Vlan1 and Vlan2.

VLANs don't work that way. It doesn't make any sense to create "VLan3 with Vlan1 and Vlan2." *Ports* can have multiple VLANs; a VLAN cannot nest more VLANs. Each VLAN is an isolated L2 network and is not connected to other VLANs *except through a router.*

> I wanted to balance the load of the internet connections. Yes, I know I should use a Load Balancer for this, but I wonder if it could work by just ussing the switch and if it would be "smart" enough to balance the traffic of the internet connections.

No, it's an L2 switch, it specifically doesn't have any "smart" that would allow that. If a PC decides to send a packet to router #1 by MAC address, the switch will forward the packet to router #1, that's all an L2 switch does.

If you plan to connect multiple routers (each with its own connection) to the same VLAN, your PCs will just pick one router and stick with it. (For example, they'll see both DHCP offers and will just choose one at random.)

In general, it's like saying "I know I should use a screwdriver, but maybe I could just hammer the screw in".